# Recovering MySQL data from external drive

Tags: mysql

AN older PC I was using has decided to give up completely but I've at least salvaged the HDD and mounted it on an external drive to the new Linux box (running Ubuntu Server 22.04). I'm trying to get the data off the old drive into the new installation so I can still work with the data on it. What's the easiest wary to get this done? (Me and MySQL have had many fallings out in the past!!) Thanks.

UPDATE
I've copied across a folder from within the old mysql folder to the new one but it isn't listed in the lists of databases. I tried to create it in mysql but it told me the schema directory already exists, so at least I'm in the right place.

Comment: if youre using `xampp` or `lampp`, locate the folder `lampp` in your base drive. cd into it and locate `mysql` folder and copy it. Then rename the current one you just installed and paste the one you copied. By that, you should be able to access your data.

Comment: So the order of events would be: 1. rename mysql folder on new drive (in var/lib/) 2. copy old files into there. I take it that destroys any users I've added on the new system?

Comment: I am a window user, and thats how i usually solve the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to copy in individual databases at the moment but it doesn't then pick it up in mysql itself. Grrrrr.

Comment: try replace the file and login. then, dump all the databases.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! Copied out the new mysql folder and swapped in the entire new one. As I wanted a clean install I then dumped the databases I wanted and swapped the original folder back before importing the dumped sql files. Phew!